# how to add one extra temporary entity in collection returned by LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

here my code-

```
List<ReservationSlotLimitDetailEntity> sorted = (from p in slotLimitCollection.OfType<ReservationSlotLimitDetailEntity>()
            where p.DayOfTheWeek == dayOfTheWeek
            select p).ToList<ReservationSlotLimitDetailEntity>();
```

I want to sort in such a way so that it will add on more temp column "DayName" based on condition such that `if dayOfTheWeek==1 DayName=Monday` and  `if dayOfTheWeek==2 DayName=Tuesday` and so on.

Comment: Is `DayName` a property on `ReservationSlotLimitDetailEntity`, or one you want to add?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `string DayName` as a property of the ReservationSlotLimitDetailEntity class
2. Add a function `GetDayName(int dayOfTheWeek)` that translates dayOfTheWeek values into the text that you want (switch structure, `case 1: return "Monday"`, etc.
3. After you retrieve your data, do the following:

   `sorted.ForEach(x => x.DayName = GetDayName(dayOfTheWeek);`